# How to remove part of the string from one character to another in php

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a URL string like

```
http://mydomain.com/status/statusPages/state/stack:3/my_link_id:1#state-9
```

I want to remove `my_link_id:1` from this string. I know I can use any string replace function like

```
$goodUrl = str_replace('my_link_id:1', '', $badUrl);
```

But the problem is, the integer part is dynamic. I mean in `my_link_id:1` the `1` is dynamic. It is the ID of the link and it can be from `0 to any number`.  So I want to remove `my_link_id:along with any dynamic number from the string`.

What I think I should remove part of the string from last `/` to `#`. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expressions:

```
$goodUrl = preg_replace('/(my_link_id:[0-9]+)/ig', '', $badUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace() php function

```
http://in1.php.net/preg_replace
```

CODE:

```
  <?php  $string = "http://mydomain.com/status/statusPages/state/stack:3/my_link_id:1#state-9";       
       echo  $result = preg_replace('/(my_link_id:[0-9]+)/si', '', $string);
    ?>
```

Output :

```
http://mydomain.com/status/statusPages/state/stack:3/#state-9
```

Answer (score 0):

May following help you

```
$strUrl = "http://mydomain.com/status/statusPages/state/stack:3/my_link_id:1#state-9";
$finalUrl = preg_replace('/(my_link_id:[0-9]+)/i', '', $strUrl);
echo $finalUrl;
```

and If you want remove also last / and # you follow this code

```
$strUrl = "http://mydomain.com/status/statusPages/state/stack:3/my_link_id:1#state-9";
$finalUrl = preg_replace('/(\/my_link_id:[0-9]+#)/i', '', $strUrl);
echo $finalUrl;
```